# Font size on image captions on mobile

Tags: images, css, query, mobile

I am using this css code on my theme in order to get the styling under an image in a post:

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:   #F2F2F2;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

When using it on mobile, the text is to big, and does not reduce size as the rest of the content. Any tips to how I can fix this? Maybe a media query in the code? How would the code look then?

Thanks a lot for all help!

Answer (score 1):

Please Use

**font-size: 2.5vw;**

it is  responsive and set according to  size.

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text { **font-size: 16px** !important; color: #000000; text-align: center; background-color: #F2F2F2; padding-top: 1px; margin: 1px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the principles of what's probably going on. (Fixing it without guesswork would require access to all your CSS.)

If (most of) your font sizes are automatically reducing on mobile, then you probably already have a media query in your CSS, something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    [some kind of CSS specifying font size]
}
```

This lets you specify CSS variations specifically for devices with a max width of 768px, so most cellphones and portrait tablets.

However, you have `!important` after your `font-size` for `.wp-caption .wp-caption-text`. This basically tells the browser to ignore any other CSS rules that would normally override it: your caption will be that font size, no matter what—and that includes ignoring any CSS that adjusts the font for mobile devices. `!important` is an ugly hack, and rarely needed.

So how to fix it? You first need to remove `!important` from your `.wp-caption .wp-caption-text`. If your caption font size is no longer 16px on a standard desktop view, you need to find out which CSS rule is overriding it. One way is to use a live inspector in a browser, like Safari's web inspector (Command-Shift-I on any page, after Preferences > Advanced > Show develop menu), and investigate where it's getting the font size from. Alternatively, look through your CSS and see if a font size for captions is specified more specifically (e.g. `body #my-main-div .wp-caption .wp-caption-text`).

Once you've found the culprit, and your font size is now 16px for captions on desktop view, then you can add a different captions font size to your `@media` query for mobile, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css as below

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) { 
  .wp-caption .wp-caption-text { font-size: 14px !important  } 
}
```